# Adding a title page in the middle of a beamer pressentation

Tags: beamer, titles, presentations

I would like to add a title page in the middle of my beamer presentation so that it does include only the title but not also the date, logo, author name and so on. So basically, I would like to add this page: [image]

in the middle of my presentation WITHOUT logo (IMT) and my name, but only "Optimal data collection design in machine learning" in the middle of the page. The technique I am currently adopting is thee following:

1. Create a .tex file called title2.tex looking like this:

```
\section{}

\title[]{Optimal data collection design in machine learning}
%\subtitle[]{}
%\author[]{}
%\institute{}
%\date{}
\maketitle
```

2. Put in the main.tex file this command: `\include{title2} % <= here comes the file created the part`.

However, this produces the picture above (i.e. with logo and name). So I am wondering if there is a way to tell `\maketitle` not to reproduce also the logo and the name but just the title and put it in the middle of the page.

Thank you

Comment: Would `\frame{\sectionpage}` work for you?

Comment: This happens because subtitle, author, etc. is still configured as before and would need to be overwritten, but this isn't possible dynamically afaik.
So I would just define the title at the beginning of the document as ``\mytitle`` and just use it where I need it. This way I can change it without worrying to much about it.

Comment: Have you tried to use the other commands (except `\title`) with empty arguments, i.e., `\subtitle{}\author{}\institute{}\date{}\maketitle`?

Comment: @gernot actually I did not. Thank you!

Comment: @JasperHabicht thank you for the comment. This also worked!

Comment: @PatrickAbraham thank you for the comment. That was what I was thinking to do in principle but I do not know how to customize the title page actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle` to insert the title in the same colour/font as it is shown on the title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title[]{Optimal data collection design in machine learning}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}[plain]
\centering
\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```